# How to disable First letter capitalization in RadEditor control in asp.net webform

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, radeditor

I am trying to edit the html formatted string in RadEditor control. Its a simple

```
<table style="width: 100%; font-family: Verdana;"> 
<tbody> 
<tr> <td>a</td></tr>
<tr> <td>b</td></tr>
<tr> <td>c</td></tr>
</tbody> </table>
```

but while debugging, the out put of RadEditor in code behind is like :

```
  <Table Style="Width: 100%; Font-Family: Verdana;"> 
  <Tbody> 
  <Tr><Td>A</Td></Tr>
  <Tr> <Td>B</Td></Tr>
  <Tr> <Td>C</Td></Tr>
  </Tbody></Table>
```

it making each first character Capital. Is there any mode to set ? 
Following is my aspx code to render :

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="editorBody" Runat="server" Skin="WebBlue" ContentAreaCssFile="~/css/EditorContentAreaStyles.css" BackColor="White" EnableResize="False" Height="600px" >
    <CssFiles>
          <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/css/EditorCSSToApply.css" />
    </CssFiles>
    <Content>

    </Content>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

Same code working fine in another form.

Comment: @user3633383: OP is talking about the tags, not the rendered output.

Comment: Exactly. But this modification is happning by Editor control itself.

Comment: Make sure that the ConvertToXhtml filter is enabled. See this help article for more information: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/content-filters

Also try to remove the contents of the EditorCSSToApply.css file and test again.